# jquery mobile search button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have implemented a listview in my project (**jQuery Mobile**) and add a the textbox for the search.

But I want to show the listview first and only when the user clicks on the button to search open a textbox over the list.

Here is my code:

```
 <a data-role="button" href="#" class="search">Show Search box</a>

    <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Pesquisa Contacto..." data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="d" style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;top:10px">
      <li>
        <a href="index.html">
          <h3>jQuery Team</h3>    
          <p><strong>Boston Conference Planning</strong></p>
          <p>In preparation for the upcoming conference in Boston, we need to start gathering a list of sponsors and speakers.</p>
          <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>9:18</strong>AM</p>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#p33', function () {    
 $('form.ui-listview-filter').hide();
});
$(document).on('click', '.search', function () {
 $('form.ui-listview-filter').show();
});
```

Comment: You want to hide the search box, until a button is clicked?

Comment: yes this is what i try to do...

Comment: i have update the code .. with the help from Ishank... but says error loading page

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Mt46d/

Comment: this is it... how it works with toogle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Mt46d/)**

Hide Search box.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#pageID', function () {    
 $('form.ui-listview-filter').hide();
});
```

Show it on button click. The button has class `search`.

```
$(document).on('click', '.search', function () {
 $('form.ui-listview-filter').show();
});
```

Comment: Omar... thanks for the help... but nothing happend...have i to change the page ID?? sorry im new in jquery

Comment: put the page id where the listview is located. and give the button a class `search` like in the demo i made. @user2232273

Comment: have you add a button? @user2232273

Comment: yes.. like yours.. look on my code below pls... and thank very much for your help...

Comment: I mean this `<a data-role="button" href="#" class="search">Show Search box</a>`. welcome @user2232273 :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29599/discussion-between-user2232273-and-omar)

Answer (score 3):

One way is - Have the Mark up as-

```
<form id ="searchForm"class="ui-listview-filter ui-bar-c" role="search" style="display:none;"><div  class="ui-input-search ui-shadow-inset ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-shadow ui-icon-searchfield ui-body-c"><input placeholder="Filter items..." data-type="search" class="ui-input-text ui-body-c"><span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all"><span class="ui-btn-text">clear text</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span></a></div></form>
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Pesquisa Contacto..." data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="d" 
           style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px;top:10px">
<li><a href="index.html">           
                <h3>jQuery Team</h3>
                <p><strong>Boston Conference Planning</strong></p>
                <p>In preparation for the upcoming conference in Boston, we need to start gathering a list of sponsors and speakers.</p>
                <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>9:18</strong>AM</p>      
            </a></li>
            </ul>
```

Note that `<form>` has `style="display:none;"` as `inline css`.

Now, unhide/hide the Search form on  the button click action- something like-

```
$(document).on("click","#BUTTON-SELECTOR",function(){
             $("searchForm").toggle();
});
```

Comment: i have update my code with your solution..  but when i click on button i have added: error loading page, maybe i have selected the wrong class?

Comment: make sure u add the jQuery part at correct place and all the needed jQuery and jQuery Mobile .js and .css are included in the html page